# Share a clustered materialized view permissions error - default permissions for roles not view or table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to cluster the original table for a materialized view I am creating and am using [this](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-materialized.html#label-clustering-base-table-and-materialized-view) as a reference. However I am running into permission errors when trying to add permissions to the view to another user with the SYSADMIN role.

```
USE WAREHOUSE "TEST...";
USE DATABASE "TEST";

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ArticleLibrary (id int, Title string, Genre string, Viewed number, date_captured timestamp );
INSERT INTO ArticleLibrary VALUES
   (1,  'The Kite Runner',   'Non-Fiction',  10, CURRENT_DATE() ),
   (2,  'The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-time',    'Fiction',      20 , CURRENT_DATE());

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW Article_Library_view_date
    COMMENT='Test view'
    AS
    SELECT ID, TITLE, GENRE, date_captured FROM ArticleLibrary;


ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW Article_Library_view_date CLUSTER BY(to_date(date_captured),genre);

SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS;

SELECT * FROM Article_Library_view_date CLUSTER;

//CREATE SCHEMA test_schema;
//GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA TEST.test_schema to SYSADMIN;
```

I tried in the interface to add modify permissions to SYSADMIN from the SECURITYADMIN role, however it was created by another SYSADMIN role. How do I troubleshoot the roles?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the GRANT SELECT statement is missing the word ROLE before SYSADMIN.  Other than that I am not sure what to make of the code because the schema is created after the view, so where is the view being created and by which role?